# Is it possible to adapt a input parameter to take a pointer instead of a reference?

Tags: c++

I am doing something like:

```
std::vector<T> Ints;
std::find_if(Ints.begin(),Ints.end(),f);

bool f(T * input)
```

Is it possible to adapt f so it can be used in by the find template?

Comment: No. The template is written to pass by reference. Why do you care anyway? For all intents and purposes, this is the same here. And surely you meant `std::find_if`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Predicate are the requirements

Comment: yes I meant find_if, yeah I can create a f2(const T & input) {return f(&input)} but I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid this

Comment: I still don't see why it makes a difference. There is nothing you can do with a pointer here that you can't do with a reference.

Comment: Yes I know, I just want to avoid creating a new function just for this

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda:

```
std::find_if(Ints.begin(), Ints.end(), [](const T& t) { return f(&t); });
```

If you can’t use C++11, you can write a generic adapter using templates:

```
template <typename T, bool (*predicate)(const T*)>
bool ReferenceToPointer(const T& t) { return predicate(&t); }

std::find_if(Ints.begin(), Ints.end(), ReferenceToPointer<int, f>);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Benjamin! So in both cases a new function will be created, good to know that there is no way to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a lambda expression, and you need an ad-hoc wrapper, you can always do the following.

```
void your_func()
{
  struct hack
  {
    static void pred_wrap (int& i) { pred(&i); }
  };

  std::find_if(Ints.begin(),Ints.end(), hack::pred_wrap);
}
```

Note that this is more than a bit hackish, and I only offer it for completeness.